# Check string against array of strings (password validation)?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

I've been googling around but can't seem to find this answer anywhere, weirdly. I need to check a single string against an array of strings, to see if any of the array strings are contained by the original string.

**So, I need to check if the password contains any of the strings, not if it is equal.**

Eg:

```
var password = 'word2'
var arrayOfStrings = ['word', 'another', 'third']

if (password.indexOf(arrayOfStrings) >= 0) {
  // valid
} else {
  // not valid
}
```

Wherein `password` is not valid.

Comment: 1) Minor error, fixed now. 2) How is this inconsistent? 3) "I need to check a single string against an array of strings".

Thanks for being so helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you try to check if your password contains any word of the array. Just loop it :)

```
for (var i=0, len=arrayOfStrings; i < len; i++) {
   if (password.indexOf(arrayOfStrings[i]) !=-1) {
      break;
      // EQUALS!!
   } else {
      // NOT EQUALS!!
   }
}
```

Since ES6, the newest vestion of JavaScript, you can use `string.include(string)`. But I have no experience with it.

Comment: Hi, I need to check if the password _contains_ any of the strings, not if it is equal.